# Href link to div on same page only works once

Tags: html

My problem is that I have an href link which, upon clicking, should bring the user down to a div with an id that corresponds to the href value.  Although the link works perfectly fine on the first time it gets clicked, it doesn't work after that.  The link just seems to go dead.  If I scroll back up the page and click the link again, it does nothing. I've tried to search all over for an answer but can't find anything.  Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Before you get rain of down-votes please add code.

Comment: In your url www.thisismylink.com when you click the link and it jumps to the corresponding div it adds into your url www.thisismylink.com/#jumpdiv which means it has been appended to already, you have to clear it using javascript hash removal.